# Assistance debugging undefined variable

Tags: php

The below code generates the following errors. I was hoping someone would be able to assist me in debugging it.

> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: tmp in .../index.php on line 57
>
> Undefined index: Response in .../index.php on line 59

```
<?php
// include config file
include_once './includes/config.inc.php';

// list of available distances
$distances = array(
    200=>'200 Miles',
    100=>'100 Miles',
    50=>'50 Miles',
);


if(isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
    
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='get_nearby_stores') {
        
        if(!isset($_POST['lat']) || !isset($_POST['lng'])) {
            
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>0,'msg'=>'Coordinate not found'));
        exit;
        }
        
        // support unicode
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
        // category filter
        if(!isset($_POST['products']) || $_POST['products']==""){
            $category_filter = "";
        } else {
            $category_filter = " AND cat_id='".$_POST['products']."'";
        }
        
        $sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(".$_POST['lat'].") ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( longitude ) - RADIANS(".$_POST['lng'].") ) + SIN( RADIANS(".$_POST['lat'].") ) * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM stores WHERE status=1 AND approved=1 ".$category_filter." HAVING distance <= ".$_POST['distance']." ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0,60";
    
        
        
        
        echo json_stores_list($sql);
    }
exit;
}


$errors = array();

if($_POST) {
    if(isset($_POST['address']) && empty($_POST['address'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter your address';
    } else {

            
        $google_api_key = '';

        $region = 'us';

        
        
        $xml = convertXMLtoArray($tmp);
        
        if($xml['Response']['Status']['code']=='200') {
            
            $coords = explode(',', $xml['Response']['Placemark']['Point']['coordinates']);
            
            if(isset($coords[0]) && isset($coords[1])) {
                
                $data = array(
                    'name'=>$v['name'],
                    'address'=>$v['address'],
                    'latitude'=>$coords[1],
                    'longitude'=>$coords[0]
                );

            
                $sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(".$coords[1].") ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( longitude ) - RADIANS(".$coords[0].") ) + SIN( RADIANS(".$coords[1].") ) * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM stores WHERE status=1 HAVING distance <= ".$db->escape($_POST['distance'])." ORDER BY distance ASC  LIMIT 0,60";
                
                $stores = $db->get_rows($sql);

            
                if(empty($stores)) {
                    $errors[] = 'Stores with address '.$_POST['address'].' not found.';
                }
            } else {
                $errors[] = 'Address not valid';
            }
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Entered address'.$_POST['address'].' not found.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: dont make me count to 57 **please**

Comment: Sorry Dagon. Thanks for your input GolezTrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one line where the variable `tmp` is used, and it's on this line:

```
$xml = convertXMLtoArray($tmp);
```

In this case, the variable is used as input in a function, so the variable must exist. Since it doesn't occur anywhere in the code, it isn't assigned yet, and so you get the error.

Now, it's hard to say how to fix this, since I don't know what convertXMLtoArray expects. I would expect that it wants to have some XML (either as as string, or as an XML document object) as input and would  return an array. So in that case `$tmp` should contain XML, and the resulting array will be stored in the variable named `$xml`, which is a poor name, given the circumstances.

Since there is also mention of a Google api key, it seems that you accidentally removed the piece of code that would get XML contents from a Google service.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you this error because the `$tmp` variable at line 57 doesn't exist.